# Retrieve row sum from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, joomla

I use the code below to retrieve data from mysql database. This gives me a single result, and I cannot understand the logic how it is generated. What I want instead is to get the SUM of the total_amount from database only in condition that contribution_page_id is 1 and currency is RUB. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('total_amount')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('civicrm_contribution'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('contribution_page_id') . ' = '. $db->quote('1'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('currency') . ' = '. $db->quote('RUB'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadResult();
echo $results;
?>;
```

Comment: sum is done to add two or more results. why to sum when the result is only single value? To get sum use `SUM(total_amount)` **function**.

Comment: the result should not be a single value. I need php to calculate all the fields in total_amount row that coincide with contribution_page_id 1 and currency RUB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should use the `sum()` function:

```
$query->select('sum('.$db->quoteName('total_amount').')');
$query->from($db->quoteName('civicrm_contribution'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('contribution_page_id') . ' = '. $db->quote('1'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('currency') . ' = '. $db->quote('RUB'));
```

If you however want to have a table with the sum of each currency (one per line), you would use the `group by` clause of sql:

```
$query->select($db->quoteName('currency'));
$query->select('sum('.$db->quoteName('total_amount').')');
$query->from($db->quoteName('civicrm_contribution'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('contribution_page_id') . ' = '. $db->quote('1'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('currency') . ' = '. $db->quote('RUB'));
$query->group($db->quoteName('currency'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Joomla uses prefixes when defining a database table in a query. You need to use `#__` before the table name like so:

```
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__civicrm_contribution'));
```

Comment: No, this is not that case, I have installed CiviCRM component that has no prefixes in the database.